# Splitting string in mysql every n value

Tags: mysql

I have this blob field in a MySQL database and its quite lengthy and I'm needing to split up the values every 4 bytes, the data is displayed in hex variables.

```
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
```

This is a sample of the data and I'm just wanting to split it up to look like 7A08 0040 9505 0700 0100 0000 0000 0000 3209 0042 and so on to place into their own columns.

I've done a lot of searching but I've not been able to find anything that will allow me to do what I'm asking and any help would be appreciated. I need to be able to do this in MySQL only.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version. Create a fiddle with some sample data (2 rows 10-15 bytes each is enough) and show desired output for this data.

Comment: It's 1 field I'm needing to split, not multiple rows, and I provided a sample of the data that is in the field above and how I'm wanting it split. There isn't anything I can put in fiddle that would better explain what I'm trying to accomplish. I want the long length of data split every 4 bytes, the whole length of the field.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT UNHEX(LEFT(HEX(val), 8)) part,
                UNHEX(SUBSTRING(HEX(val) FROM 9)) slack
         FROM test
         UNION ALL
         SELECT UNHEX(LEFT(HEX(slack), 8)),
                UNHEX(SUBSTRING(HEX(slack) FROM 9))
         FROM cte
         WHERE slack != '' )
SELECT part
FROM cte;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c195bbe7528ded66596bfd834f14993)

---

> That would work except I'm having to use **MySQL 5.6** for the program to work properly.

```sql
SELECT /* UNHEX(SUBSTRING(HEX(val) FROM 1+8*(num1.num*100+num2.num*10+num3.num) FOR 8)) part */
       SUBSTRING(HEX(val) FROM 1+8*(num1.num*100+num2.num*10+num3.num) FOR 8) part
FROM test
JOIN (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) num1
JOIN (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) num2
JOIN (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) num3
HAVING part != ''
ORDER BY num1.num*100+num2.num*10+num3.num
```

The query assumes that max. length of BLOB value is 4000 bytes. If the length is greater then add proper `numN` tables count.

Comment: That would work except I'm having to use MySQL 5.6 for the program to work properly. I've tried to upgrade before but one of the scripts required to running the program I've not been able to upgrade. Thank you though.

Comment: @Edenost Edit your question, add this CRITICAL info into.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to split up the data you can use Substring('Text',start,length).

However to assign values to an unspecified number of columns, is not how SQL normally work. I would suggest you make a subtable to contain the substrings and relate the main table to the subtable with af key.

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE @text_Sub NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @i int -- integration variable
DECLARE @foreignKey int --relation key to main table

SET @foreignKey = 1 -- Must be adjusted for each string you want to pass
SET @text = '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

-- this should be permanent table
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
                        Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                        ForeignKey int,
                        Text NVARCHAR(10)
                        )

-- loop over text and insert into af subtable
SET @i = 0
SET @text_Sub = SUBSTRING(@text,@i,10)

WHILE (LEN(@text_Sub) > 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TempTable
    (   ForeignKey,Text)
    VALUES
    (   @foreignKey,@text_Sub)
    SET @i = @i +10
    SET @text_Sub = SUBSTRING(@text,@i,10)
END

--Test the subtable have been filled
SELECT COUNT( *),MAX(Id)
FROM #TempTable

-- Assume you have a table called Table insert the relationkey/foreignKey
-- INSERT INTO Table
-- (ForeignKey)
-- VALUES
-- (@foreignKey)
-- WHERE 'SomeIdentifier'

--Clean up the temp table
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```